# How to do backward compatibility in android?

Tags: android

I am currently working with minimum API level 21 and I want to change this to API level 15.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Use the compatibility library

Comment: you just change it, and see which code gives you compile errors, and fix them.

Comment: Open the Gradle file (or manifest). Set the minimum SDK to 15. See if it compiles, let it error, fix, and repeat.

Comment: Although there're already answers to this question on SO, none of them is younger than 4 years. So I would suggest to rethink good answers instead of closing this question

Comment: what you tried and what problem you are facing?????

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger The documentation isn't good enough? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: @cricket As usual, the documentation is close to the absolute minimum. A little verbosity here and there would do wonders. E.g. what about a section on typical traps and pitfalls (e.g. best practice with `Notification`, `Display.getHeight`, `UsbDevice.getProductName`, SD card access, runtime permission check, ...).